# Inserting data Issue with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

This code has to work but it does not. When I use the echo $sql query on mysql workbench it actually adds the data to database. I think there is something about mysql_query method. It has been two days I am struggling with this thing a little bit of help would be awesome.

Here is the code

```
    <?php 


     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
     include('mysqli_connect.php');



    $AracMarkasi = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['AracMarkasi']);
    $AracPlakasi = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['AracPlakasi']);
    $AracRengi = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['AracRengi']);
    $AracModeli = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['AracModeli']);
    $AracSahibiAdi = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 
    $_POST['AracSahibiAdi']);
    $AracSahibiSoyadi = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 
    $_POST['AracSahibiSoyadi']);
    $AracSahibiAdresi = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 
    $_POST['AracSahibiAdresi']);
    $AracSahibiTC = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 
    $_POST['AracSahibiTC']);
    $DosyaNO = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['DosyaNO']);
    $IcraDairesiNO = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 
    $_POST['IcraDairesiNO']);
    $Durum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Durum']);




    $sql = "INSERT INTO deptcar.arac_tablosu (AracPlakası,AracMarkasi,AracModeli,AracRengi,AracSahibiAdi,AracSahibiSoyadi,AracSahibiTCKimlik,AracSahibiAdresi,AracDurum,DosyaNO,IcraDairesiNO) VALUES('$AracPlakasi','$AracMarkasi','$AracModeli','$AracRengi','$AracSahibiAdi','$AracSahibiSoyadi','$AracSahibiTC','$AracSahibiAdresi','$Durum','$DosyaNO','$IcraDairesiNO')";

    echo "$sql";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    echo "$result";

    if(!$result)
    { die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());}
    else{echo "Entered data successfully\n";}

    mysql_close($conn);
    }
    ?>
```

And this part is output

> Connected
>
> INSERT INTO deptcar.arac_tablosu
> (AracPlakası,AracMarkasi,AracModeli,AracRengi,AracSahibiAdi,AracSahibiSoyadi,AracSahibiTCKimlik,AracSahibiAdresi,AracDurum,DosyaNO,IcraDairesiNO)
> VALUES('ads','ads','yt','','rhrg','hg','dhg','ggd','SahaPersoneli','gfh','hdg')
>
> Could not enter data:

Comment: How did you made the table ? Are you sure you don't have a NOT NULL on AracRengi column ?

Comment: please read better the mysql_error(), echo mysql_error()

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, as are showing the uses of `mysqli_query` and `mysql_error`. Change the latter to `mysqli_error`, and you might have a berret idea of why your statement doesn't execute.

Comment: @Superdrac I dont have NOT NULL in any of them.

Comment: AracPlakası what is that last character ? it doesn´t seems to be a i.  i ı i ı. It could be a carackter which cant be read

Comment: @roberto06 now I am having an error = mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in.

Comment: I'm guess 'mysqli_connect.php' either doesn't specifiy the right database, or the username doesn't have write permission.  Make a [mcve] and see if you can insert something simple and work your way up.

Comment: @gaban Yeah well, reading the [`mysqli_error` documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) tells you that you need to add the connection link as parameter.

Comment: If it works than you copy the insert command to your mysql workbench, than it could be really a problem with that character.

Comment: @Doomenik Omg Sir thank you, that i character though. It took me two days gosh but at the same time when I copy paste this query to workbench it still inserts the data. I had to change the AracPlakası to AracPlakasi column. I think MySQL does not provide option to name the column  with non eng characters.

Comment: @gaban it would be even better if you print the error you are getting. i mean the trace of error. and also try to share your schema code for the table in which you are getting error in your database.

Comment: @gaban No problem, glad I could help. Getting problems like this every day on international projects :D

Comment: Your `$_POST['AracRengi']` has no value and we don't know if the (missing) form's element is at fault. Best that you check if *all* the POST arrays are *not* empty before attempting to insert and use php's error reporting. The questions lacks code and db schema detail. Either that, or it's a column insert mismatch.